# $x \mapsto x^TAx$ determines A for symmetric A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For some unknown $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, if $A$ is symmetric, I think the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x^{\top}Ax$ determines what $A$ is. I think this is true, and I should've known how to prove this, but right now I'm not very sure on how to proceed.

One always have $x^{\top}Ax = \operatorname{tr}(x^{\top}Ax) =\langle x x^{\top},A \rangle$. This is very useful in specifying the Hessian when the Hessian is symmetric, especially for functions where the domain is a matrix.

Does anyone mind sharing a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you were only asking for a hint so I deleted my other answer. My hint is consider $x \mapsto x^TAx$ applied to simple linear combinations of standard basis vectors.

Comment: Thank you! I got it, so you determine the diagonal first, by considering x being the standard basis vectors, and you consider the case $x$ contains 2 1s and the rest being 0, since $A$ is symmetric, this would determine other entries. Is this your approach?

Comment: Yup that is it.